# Reading inputs in java

Tags: java

Hello everyone I'm trying to improve my Java skills by solving some problems from ACM, now the thing is my sample input looks like this :

```
 3 100
 34 100
 75 250
 27 2147483647
 101 304
 101 303
 -1 -1
```

So at first I'm just trying to read them but its not working here is the java code:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));
        while (stdin.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(stdin.nextInt() + " and the next " + stdin.nextInt());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to send these inputs as an argument, and not by reading them from file, here is how:

[image]

The program just spins(executes) but not printing anything. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arguments you have specified in your wizard are not input to the program via std in.  Instead, they are passed in in the `String[] args` arguments passed into your `main` method.  As it looks as though you are running in Eclipse, you can go to the Console tab that gets generated and type into that window.  Alternatively, you can iterate over the `args` param to get those values.

Answer (score 1):

I am not using Eclipse, but this should print the numbers you have inputed. 
You are passing the numbers as string arguments, so this: "3 100" is actually equal to

```
String str = 3 + " " + 100;
```

This should print the numbers:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    for (String arg : args)
    {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
}
```

After you start the program you should provide some numbers as an input.